# LinqToExcel Rounding decimal numbers when reading in data

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I'm using LinqToExcel to read in data from an excel spreadsheet. However, when reading in data with numbers decimal places, it will round to the second decimal place. How do i stop this?

E.G excel data = 12.1552456

But LinqToExcel will only read the data but only return 12.16

Comment: show your implementation, how you are reading the excel, where you are carrying out the conversion etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an issue with the OleDb adapter that LinqToExcel uses, and not LinqToExcel itself.